# Java - creation of multiple object of a same kind and storing them in 2d arrayList map

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I need to create 30 objects of the same kind and their name should start with a capital letter e.g "K" and after the letter i need the index of the object
e.g K1 ; K2 ... K30
Is there any way to enter a loop which has a counter and ***which will work properly***
something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i<20;i++){
K k = new K();
k.setName("k" + i)
}
```

I also have a map which is 2d ArrayList 20x20
and all this object need to have a random position x and y into this array list 
i could generate random numbers easily but how to use them to put the objects in the array list 
Thank you for your time !

Comment: Well, you've created 20 instances; it's a simple change to create 30.

Comment: this is just an example i've wrote but is this going to work k.setName("k" + i)
and how to put the objects into the array list. I assume that they need Position x and y but what's the thing i need to do with x and y to put the objects inside the ArrayList

Comment: We don't know. Is there a method for the K class called "setName"?

Comment: @DimitarVelikov if you put a semi-colon at the end of that sentence and as long as your class K has a "name" attribute with a setter called setName() it will. On the other hand, why don't you give it a spin and test it?

Comment: well, yes there is

Comment: Then outside the fact there is no arraylist you have created to store these multiple copies of a K object, yes, this code works.

Comment: Ok cheers guys, could you advise me for the Array list now ?

Comment: Please show how you declare and initialize your arraylists.

Comment: public class GridWorld {

 private final int gridSize = 20;

 private ArrayList<Being>[][] gridWorld;


 public GridWorld() {
  gridWorld = new ArrayList[gridSize][gridSize];
 }

Comment: That's an array of `ArrayList`s, not a 2D `ArrayList`.

Comment: I need a map 20x20 where I can store multiple objects of kind K or similar so im pretty sure that will work

Comment: That could be `K[][] grid = new K[20][20];`, or `ArrayList<ArrayList<K>> grid = new ArrayList<>(); /* some logic to populate it */`. `ArrayList<K>[][]` is a 2D array of lists, i.e. you can store a basically unlimited number of `K`s in each of the array elements' lists.

Comment: ok lets leave the things this way.. my question is how to put K in position e.g x=5 y=10 into this array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a class K, with `setName()` method, you can do the following:

```
List<K> list = new ArrayList<K>(); 
for(int i=1 ; i<=30 ; i++){
    K k = new K();
    k.setName("K" + i);
    list.add(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just set the limit to 30, if you want a list for your objects, you have to create a list and add objects, for example

```
List<K> kObjects = new ArrayList<K>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
    K k = new K();
    k.setName("K" + i);
    kObjects.add(k);
}
```

Hope it helps to you